# What is meant by AngularJS element?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJS. I was reading the https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives : "You do NOT have to wrap AngularJS elements in jQuery()"

What is meant by an AngularJS element?
In Jquery, if I have a DOM element, say by using `document.getElementByID()` and if I want to make it a jquery element with access to all of its awesome functions, I will simply say

```
 var domElement = document.getElementByID("elemID");
 var $domElement = $(domElement); (To cache the element)
```

So, if in angular I dont have to wrap the DOM element as in Jquery, then can I simply query the DOM and access it and still be able to access all the angular methods.
If so, how it is done? Is it because of the ng-app binding?
Are all DOM elements inside ng-app internally accessed by Angular and turned to equivalent AngularJS elements?

Comment: Did you read the rest of that wiki? It explains that they’re already jqlite objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiki page is talking about the elements passed by Angular as arguments to the compile and link functions of the directive:

```
link: function LinkingFunction($scope, $element, $attributes) { ... }
                                       ^-- here
```

If you get an element from the DOM using `document.getElementById()`, it won't be wrapped in jQuery automatically.

Comment: Just wanted to add you can also take a regular DOM element and pass it to angular.element(myDomElement) similar to $(myDomElement).

Comment: @shaunhusain and don't forget to $compile.